# Use Object.watch() on an "independent" variable?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, watch

Perhaps I'm missing something major, but is there a way to use `Object.watch()` on variables that exist independent of objects?

I'm a bit new to JS, and couldn't find any kind of global object that my variable was attached to.

(Also, just using this for debugging, so the fact that it's only supported in Mozilla browsers isn't a problem.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global scope in a browser is actually the `window` object, so if your variable is a global variable, it's actually attached to the `window` object. So you can access it as `window.variableName` just as well as simply `variableName`. And thus you should be able to say:

```
window.watch('variableName', callback);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. (Apparently I can't accept this for another 6 minutes but I will then. (: )

Comment: If `window` is the global scope, then would you be able to just use `watch('foo', bar)`?